# How can I further limit visibility of assembla SVN's?

Tags: svn, permissions

I would like to give each team member their own SVN so I disable them from viewing the entire project. Is it possible to only let them each view one SVN? Right now I have my own FULL SVN, then they can all see "their" SVN and "others" SVN, but I would like to give them each their own SVN and not let them see any others.

Does the assembla's ACL allow for direct user permissions?

Comment: What do you mean by "their SVN" and "others SVN"? SVN is a centralized VCS, so it should be visible to all working with it. Or is your question about authorization of content? Then ask it more concrete to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Assembla. If I understand you correctly, you are looking for directory based permissioning. This is a feature that is currently in the plans. We plan to allow users to have one SVN repo with a bunch of folders and have an ACL on every directory.

Currently, you can do this level of ACL only by having multiple SVN repositories in multiple spaces. Every developer would have his own space and his own Repository and his own Tickets Tool in that space.

If you are only looking for write-level ACL (not read), you can look into Protected Branches in your SVN settings (you can prevent certain team members from committing to certain directories, they will need to use merge requests and owners can accept code).

Another feature we are working on is Space Manager. This is in beta test at the moment. We can add you to this program. This would allow you to share Tickets tool across a number of Spaces with SVN repositories. If you want to get into this program, either contact me or Assembla's support staff referencing this URL.

Comment: How would you like to be contacted?